# I am seeking an admission OR I am seeking for admission?

Tags: prepositions, articles

> I am seeking a full time PhD admission.

OR

> I am seeking for admission to the full time PhD.

Both sentence seem to me correct. Am I right?

Comment: Admission to **what**? A Doctoral program at a University? Regardless, neither of them are particularly good options. The second is particularly poor. We do not generally do proofreading here, and that's all I can see you're asking for in this question. Please note a specific point that you're confused about and we can try to help you.

Comment: What is your thinking regarding adding extra words? At best it muddles the meaning. If you don't need them, don't use them.

Comment: Actually I am  trying to write  my objective for higher studies.  I was confused regarding two sentences. I couldn't find the errors, because both of them looked good to me. Can you please rewrite it, so I can easily understand the problem I made?

Comment: @Catija, what else would it be? A full-time PhD admission to a zoo? XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second sentence is not correct, in that "for" should be left out, and the word "program" should probably be added.

**"I am seeking admission to the full time Ph.D. program."**

Comment: PhD, without periods) is acceptable to various experts and recognized style guides. See, for example, https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/programs/phd/academic-experience

Comment: There's no **one** standard for this. Even the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy) article about it allows for different versions, usually depending on where you are in the world. Regardless, that's not what this question is asking, so this answer is a bit of a non sequitur.

Answer (score 3):

We can use:

> I am seeking admission to the full-time PhD program.

or

> I seek admission to the full-time PhD program.

The second option is more formal, and therefore more appropriate when writing an objective, as you said you were doing in your comment. (I assume you are writing this for a formal or academic purpose.)

While we most often use the continuous to describe a present temporary action,

> In special circumstances, we can also use the present simple to
>   describe temporary states and actions. . . .
>
> [For example] wants and likes   *want, like, need, hate, prefer*

(Parrott, Martin. 2000. *Grammar for English Language Teachers.* Cambridge University Press, p. 155.)

Just as we would say,

*I want to apply to the full-time Ph.D. program.*

Or, *I want a cup of tea.*

Ph.D. program (with periods) is also acceptable. I would follow whichever practice the school does.